# Lenovo Not connecting to wireless networks

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo, iwlwifi

I know similar questions have been asked before but solutions aren't working in my case. I bought a brand new Ideapad 5 15ITL05, without any OS. Initially, I installed Xubuntu 20.04 on it, then the touchpad was not working and also the wifi networks were showing but not connecting.

Then I installed Xubuntu 21, the touchpad started working but the wifi still gives the same error that the password is incorrect, which is obviously not because it is a hotspot from my mobile. I tried installing drivers from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html and also followed this https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/intel-wifi.html but no luck.

WLAN + Bluetooth™ - 802.11ac 2x2 Wi-Fi + Bluetooth 5.0, M.2 Card (taken from product specifications)

some of the info about the wifi adapter and the things I tried -

```
prince@prince-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~/Desktop/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0$ uname -r
5.11.0-16-generic
```

```
prince@prince-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~/Desktop/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

```
prince@prince-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~/Desktop/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       serial: 2c:8d:b1:91:28:0a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-16-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:600323c000-600323ffff
```

```
prince@prince-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~/Desktop/iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0$ nmcli device
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp0s20f3          wifi      disconnected  --         
p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --         
lo                 loopback  unmanaged     --
```

Please help I can't figure out how to make it work and connect to the wireless network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, there was some issue with my mobile phone. It is connecting if I created the wifi hotspot without security in my mobile phone but not if it is protected. I tried this with another device and it connected successfully even if the network is password protected and no wrong password warning this time. Also, the touchpad is working fine in ubuntu 20.04